# Best practice for deploying angular 2 with spring backend

Tags: spring, angular

I am new to angular 2 and i would like to develop a project using spring for my backend and angular 2 for my front end. The question is which is the best practice to develop such project ? Putting them on the same server or different servers. There is very limited guidelines on the web for this subject. If someone points me in the right direction i would be so glad..

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd host the angular app within a CDN, then host from that CDN.

One example of this would be hosting the compiled site through S3, then using Route 53 to host the site itself.

[Tutorial on how to do this.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

The tougher part is the Java application itself. There's multiple options out there, but it depends on how the application is built, could require a servlet container, etc.

But basically, you want the static site hosting statically, not as part of the Java code. Helps with a clean separation of duties, and provides performance improvements. Then you need to figure out how to host the actual Java application.